# How to create a unique eventlistener for a label/button in Actionscript in a for loop?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

At the moment I have this in Actionscript (for Flex) to create 26 labels in a BorderContainer (ID *letters*):

```
var lettersArray:Array = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];

for(var indexLetter:String in lettersArray) {
    var labelLetter:Label = new Label();
    labelLetter.text = lettersArray[indexLetter];
    labelLetter.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function():void { getUsers(lettersArray[indexLetter]); });

    letters.addElement(labelLetter);
}
```

But when I click on a letter, only the letter Z is sent to the function *getUsers*. So when I'm creating labels from a for loop, only the eventlistener works for the last created label. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that `getUsers(lettersArray[indexLetter])` is an error as you can't access array elements like that

```
var lettersArray:Array = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];

for each(var letter:String in lettersArray) {
    var labelLetter:Label = new Label();
    labelLetter.text = letter;
    labelLetter.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function():void { getUsers(e.currentTarget.text); });

    letters.addElement(labelLetter);
}
```

Comment: Finally! Thank you! I've added _e:MouseEvent_ to the function. _getUsers(lettersArray[indexLetter])_ was always 'Z'.

Comment: Why not simply **labelLetter.text = indexLetter;**

Comment: I copied the example from the original question and only skimmed it to change the relevant part :)  Fixed now.